# Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with uniform distribution on $[-1;1]$ and $Z=\log(|X|)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with uniform distribution on $[-1;1]$ and $Z=\log(|X|)$. Calculate the probability density function of $X$.

I believe that we need to calculate the CMF (cumulative distribution function) $f_Z(z)$ and then derive it to obtain the  $f_z(z)$. However, strange things (to me) are done in my book, such as the integral calculated between $\min\{e^t,1\}$ and $\max\{-e^t ,-1\}$. Could someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

According to the details you supplied, your book seems to be taking a mechanical route that might not be very illuminating.  Instead, consider a two-step approach:

1. If $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-1,1)$, then what is the support of $Y = |X|$?  What is the probability distribution of $Y$?
2. If $Z = \log Y$, what is the support of $Z$?  What is the probability distribution of $Z$?

Edit your question to include the work that you have done to answer these questions.  If you encounter further difficulty, describe which steps at which those difficulties occur.